# Is it possible to load .ascx page in iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to load ascx page in iframe.When I try it I got a error

`The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.ascx' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.`

But when I want to load `.html` page in same location it can be load.
May i did any thing wrong ?Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't load .ascx file in an iframe for the same reason you can't load it directly in the browser. It's not a page, but rather a control. So it's meant to be used within an .aspx page.

Comment: I am thinking whether ascx or aspx, saved my time.-Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ascx is for usercontrols.

It isn't supported to request an ascx you have to create a page (aspx) for it. Another approach is to create an HttpHandler and manipulate the response.

Comment: thanks.U caught my problem.I manipulate with HTTPHandler but i got above error.May u know any links or u have any small piece of code plz share.

Comment: the most common implementation for a HTTPHandler is the ASPX or aka Page Class just have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx But remember that you have to register your custom HttpHandler's within your web.config. For more samples just have a look in your global web.config located within your Framework root dir.

Answer (score 0):

.ascx-file is not a page it is a user control. What you need to do is either make a page of it, that is, an .aspx-file and change it accordingly, or wrap it in an .aspx-file that includes your .ascx-file.